# get java version of a running java process

Tags: java, jstack

I can use jps to list running java processes and use jstack -l process_id to get a stack information of a running java process. I want to know this process runs on which java version. Is there a way to do it? I don't have to use jstack tool. thanks.

jstack -l 23819
2014-11-12 12:36:11
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000272f800 nid=0x614b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Answer (score 24):

You can do it via jcmd, like this:

```
jcmd process_id VM.version
```

Answer (score 6):

In Linux you could do

```
sudo strings /proc/<java_pid>/smaps |grep jre
```

which will produce something similar to

> 7f8ff82ac000-7f8ff82ad000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 252363860                  /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_141/jre/lib/amd64/libjaas_unix.so

From this you can clearly see what JDK version it's using.

Comment: In my case I had to `grep jvm` but thanks for the nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution with standard command would look like:

```
lsof -p PID | grep jdk
```

It gives you the list of loaded files by the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think Andrew's solution is better and probably what you are looking for. Nevertheless here's another solution:

```
ps -A | grep "^ <the pid>" | grep -o "jdk.*.jdk"
```

Output for a program I was running:

```
jdk1.8.0_05.jdk
```