# how to list running java processes on linux and windows servers and identify the java version in use

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, jvm, system

I am looking at the simplest way to retrieve from various Linux and windows servers the name of processes running with java 7 (or any other versions).
I do not wish to install tools as there are multiple servers involved.

solution at [get java version of a running java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896182/get-java-version-of-a-running-java-process) are for a single process.

any suggestions ? thx

Comment: [`jps`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jps.html) to list all running Java processes + [`jcmd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) to find VM version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `ps -ef | grep java` in Linux as it shows all JAVA applications up and running. In Windows also you should be able to use `tasklist | findstr java` in Terminal

Comment: This does not work for Java applications started with their own launchers. E.g. `grep java` won't find IDEA or Eclipse. `jps` would be a better choice.